# Can Mixpanel alert on never before seen property values?

Tags: mixpanel

Can Mixpanel alert on never before seen property values? Could not find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may I ask what the underlying use-case is?  Often when folks have asked this kind of question, it's because they want to QA their data, in which case we do have a product designed just for that - [Data Audit](https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/360028823552).

Take a look and let me know your thoughts!

Comment: We developed a system which is simple to extend by registering new components on the fly.  In order to mitigate the risk of unwanted/unknown extensions, I would like to be alerted when a never before seen component registers itself.  Looking at Data Audit, thanks!

Comment: If I am reading correctly, Data Audit does not deal with property values, which is what  we are interested in. e.g. define the domain of expected property values as all the values seen before, then alert if a property value is not in that domain